# How can I trigger an event after lazy load has loaded an image?

Tags: jquery, jquery-lazyload

I have images that need to be absolutely positioned so that the center of the image is in the center of its parent div. I already have code that does this.

I recently added the Lazy Load plugin and it works as expected. But I need a way of triggering my image centering code **after** lazy load has loaded **and** faded-in the image.

My current code is basically this:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

// Make all lazy images ready to load themselves and listen for a custom event
$("img.lazy").lazyload({ event:"delayed-lazy-load-event", effect : "fadeIn"});

});


// Wait for the iframes and other important junk to finish loading
jQuery( window ).load( function($){

// trigger lazy loading of thumbnails.
$("img.lazy").trigger("delayed-lazy-load-event")
}
```

I can't find any info about any feature of Lazy Load that lets me set a callback function to run after it runs the fadeIn effect.

Answer (score 11):

found this to work:

```
$('img.lazy').on('appear',function(){
  console.log(this)//fires this function when it appears
});
```

Comment: nice!, how can I capture 404s?

Comment: Is 'appear' the correct argument here? I have a feeling that it means 'appear in the viewport', not 'image has appeared'. For me it's triggering pretty much as soon as the script loads, not when the image has loaded.

Answer (score 4):

**Entrabiter**'s answer is actually for triggering a function when the image appears on screen, not after it has loaded. To run some code after an image has loaded (i.e. faded in), you need the 'load' argument:

```
$('img.lazy').on('load',function(){
  console.log(this)//fires this function when it appears
});
```