# Jquery Lazy Loading after image load, css is not applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lazy-loading

I'm using this plug in [jQuery Lazy - Delayed Content, Image and Background Lazy Loader](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/)

I'm trying to add image border-color and image border thickness to the image after lazy loading but it seems like it has no effect. If I press "inspect" at developer console, I can see this attributes are added to image style but its effect is not shown on screen.

HTML

```
<img class="lazy" data-src= "{{ individual_image.url }}" src="{% static 'img/image_loading.jpg' %}"style="opacity:0.3; width:150px; height:150px;>
```

JQuery

```
        $('img.lazy').Lazy({

            scrollDirection: 'vertical',                
            visibleOnly: false,               
            afterLoad: function(element) {                   
                element.css('border-width', 'thick');
                element.css('border-color', 'chartreuse');                    

            }
        });
```

Comment: might also help to use the search https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398005/jquery-lazyload-callback

Comment: bounty will be split between you and userlond, I can choose this feature when its expired

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Border-style` CSS attribute is required. Default value is `none`, so border is not displayed.

```
$('img.lazy').Lazy({
    scrollDirection: 'vertical',                
    visibleOnly: false,               
    afterLoad: function(element) {                   
        element.css('border-width', 'thick');
        element.css('border-color', 'chartreuse');
        // add border-style and border becomes visible                    
        element.css('border-style', 'solid');
    }
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/672021/)

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest doing it this way :

```
    $('img.lazy').Lazy({

        scrollDirection: 'vertical',                
        visibleOnly: false,               
        afterLoad: function(element) {                   
            element.css('border', 'thick solid chartreuse');                  

        }
    });
```

By using `border` you won't be missing any parameters! :) Also less code to do the same thing is always better.

I prepared a demo with a large file and a loading animation so you could actually notice the lazy loading before the image loads and the border takes effect.

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fryxe5pb/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the border attribute only and set it like below

```js
$('img.lazy').Lazy({

  scrollDirection: 'vertical',
  visibleOnly: false,
  afterLoad: function(element) {
    element.css('border', 'width style color');

  }
});
```